# On click highlight the tab and display the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

currently I'm trying like if I click on the tab it will change color instead of the standard color I set.How do I go about doing it because I'm using the toggle() function.

Currently I'm stuck at here.

```
$("li").click(function(){
$(this).css('background-color',"#6F0")
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eMLTB/112

Comment: Please go through http://jsfiddle.net/eMLTB/113/ is that what actually you want?

Comment: try adding `$('li').css('background-color','#2489CE')` on the click  function mate.. :)

Comment: You just need to reset the `background-color` on all `li` elements on click before setting the bg color of the current one using `$("li").css('background-color',"initial")`. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eMLTB/122/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the line of script where i placed a comment, I think after adding this solves your problem.

```
<div id="container">
<nav id="tabs">
<ul id ="ta" class="nav">
      <li id="a"><a href="#tabs-1">0</a></li>
      <li id="b"><a href="#tabs-2">5</a></li>
      <li id="c"><a href="#tabs-3">10</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabContent" id="tabs-1" >
      <h2>Testing1</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="tabContent" id="tabs-2">
      <h2>Testing2</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="tabContent" id="tabs-3">
      <h2>Testing3</h2>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And in your Script

```
var i;

$("li").each(
    function(){
$(this).click(
    function(){
    i = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $(i).toggle();
    }
);
    }
);

$("li").click(function(){
    $('li').css('background-color',"#fff");//------>I set it #fff , you Can Put here your standard color code
       $(this).css('background-color',"#6F0")
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

Hide all `.tabContent` elements on page load and show them on click of `li`.

Write:

JS:

```
$("li").click(function () {
    $($(this).find("a").attr("href")).toggle();    
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

CSS:

```
.active {
    background-color:#6F0;
}
.tabContent {
    display:none;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/eMLTB/115/)

Answer (score 1):

First, put the `class` attribute for `<li>` tag, example :

```
<ul id ="ta" class="nav">
    <li id="a" class="navi"><a href="#tabs-1">0</a></li>
    <li id="b" class="navi"><a href="#tabs-2">5</a></li>
    <li id="c" class="navi"><a href="#tabs-3">10</a></li>
</ul>
```

next, make your code like this :

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $(".navi").css('background-color', "");
    $(this).css('background-color', "#6F0");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `.toogleClass()` method.

It is similar like `.toogle()` but better for CSS manipulation.

First create class in your CSS that will represent your color and then toogle that class.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/